# Netbeans - disable CTRL+Click as shortcut for "Go To Definition"

Tags: netbeans, ide, go-to-definition

Netbeans (7.2 on Win7 Pro) has a nifty feature whereby you can hold CTRL then click variables to "Go to Definition".

The project in which I'm working is over a network share.  Because of this, my indexing is quite slow (which is fine).  The problem is, when I press CTRL, the whole interface slows down as Netbeans tries desperately to support this cool "Go to Definition" feature.

I'm in a really old project that's poorly assembled and the feature isn't much use to me anyway.  **Is there any way to turn it off?**

I press CTRL a *lot*.  I use hotkeys incessantly, and navigate across words and definitions by holding CTRL as I use the arrows.  This is slowing me down considerably and I really need to get it out of my way somehow.  I'm open to other suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you use **Ctrl + B**, I use it and it works fine

BR